# Grouped Observable CollectionView lazy loading does not trigger for iOS

Tags: .net, maui, observablecollection

I have a CollectionView containing Task items group by Type in my .NET MAUI app, with load on demand triggering when ItemThreshold is met. This behavior works fine on Android, but does not seem to trigger on iOS. Below is my code:

.xaml Collection View:

```
<CollectionView  Margin="5,0,5,0" 
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ItemSelectCommand}"    
                             SelectionMode="Single"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList}"
                             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TaskSelector}"
                             EmptyView="No Tasks to display"
                             IsGrouped="True"
                             RemainingItemsThreshold="{Binding ItemThreshold}"
                             RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreDataCommand}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                       ItemSpacing="2" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Type}" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <CollectionView.Footer>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </CollectionView.Footer>
                </CollectionView>
```

As you can see above, the LoadMoreData command should be triggered on scrolling to the last few items in the existing list when ItemThreshold is reached. The associated ViewModel is below:

.cs

```
        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task Refresh()
        {
            try
            {
                page = 1;

                (List<TaskListModel> taskList, _) = await restAPIService.GetTaskList(page);

                TaskList.Clear();
                AppendToCollection(taskList);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // catch case
            }
            finally
            {
                ItemThreshold = 0;
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task LoadMoreData()
        {
            try
            {
                page++;

                (List<TaskListModel> taskList, _) = await restAPIService.GetTaskList(page);

                if (taskList.Count > 0)
                    AppendToCollection(taskList);
                else
                    ItemThreshold = -1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // catch case
            }
        }
```

The above code works fine on Android, with the `LoadMoreData` method being called correctly at the end of the list. However, for iOS, this method is never called, hence our lazy loading does not work.

Appreciate any help :)!

We are aware that this potentially could be an existing bug of MAUI's grouped CollectionView for the iOS platform:

Grouped CollectionView lazy loading does not trigger [RemainingItemsThresholdReached] on iOS and Windows · Issue #10078 · dotnet/maui · GitHub

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10078

We are actively trying to find a workaround to this issue

Comment: Can you troubleshoot/print the exception?

Comment: May I know what exception are you referring to exactly? Presently, RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand() is not being triggered entirely, hence no exception is thrown

Comment: Apologies for the confusion if you were referring to the catch statement, that is irrelevant to my query :)

Comment: Currently, with the code snippet provided we cannot differentiate between "never called" versus "being called but an exception raised and caught".

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, I might be wrong here, the problem lies within the handling of group items. What I can find is this [repo](https://github.com/kramer-e/CollectionViewInfiniteScrollingBug) that dealing with something similar. Perhaps it works for you.

Comment: Hey Peter, we tried the repo you found. As of now, it is a usable workaround, however, it did presented another problem which we are looking into. Nonetheless, really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing as we are proceeding to use the repo presented to us by @Peter as a workaround for now.